# Obtaining Domestic Travel Insurance During Covid-19

Tags: uk, insurance, covid-19, uk-residents

We booked a holiday cottage in the UK for the end of July 2020. We neglected to purchase travel insurance when we booked it at the start of 2020 (we've learnt from this mistake). We have already started paying the balance on this trip.

So now we are looking at purchasing travel insurance but we are concerned that the Covid-19 lockdown currently in the UK, will invalidate any insurance we take out now. The optimistic estimates put the end of the lockdown around the 15th June.

Is it worth us taking out the insurance now to protect our existing deposit/holiday or is likely that all insurance policies purchased now will be invalidated if there is an extension to the lockdown?

Any guidance on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It is very unlikely that any insurance you take out now will cover anything related to the virus. Policies were being tightened up a couple of weeks ago, so I'd be surprised if any were left.

E.g. From https://www.directline.com/covid

> Insurance is there to help with unknown or unforeseeable events. As Coronavirus is now a known event, no cover is available.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking it is worth considering cover now for a future trip, but it's unlikely that a standard travel insurance policy regulated by the UK will cover you for Covid-19 related problems. So far as I'm aware, none will.

Several UK insurers aren't even selling travel insurance policies for the time being.

Compare the Market says in its online quote page:

> Following the World Health Organisation (WHO) declaring coronavirus as
>   a pandemic on the 11th March 2020, many insurance companies will
>   consider coronavirus to be a 'known event'. Insurance providers may
>   exclude known events from elements of the cover they offer.
>
> Therefore for new policies purchased after the announcement ensure you
>   check the policy wording or contact the insurer to ensure the cover
>   meets your needs.

I think that's standard now.

You may find it difficult to speak with an insurer by phone as they are swamped with claims and requests for policy amendments and refunds.

If you do find such a policy as you want, make sure you thoroughly read all the documentation.